# GIMP doesn't update graphically unless window changed

Tags: 16.04, graphics, window, gimp

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I have a computer with Intel graphics running Ubuntu 16.04 and GIMP doesn't update graphically on it unless the GIMP window is moved or minimised and then maximised. So, I mean that any interaction with the GIMP interface, whether it be selecting a tool or drawing on an image, does not update and become graphically apparent unless the GIMP window is changed in some way.

I have not observed this with other programs on this computer and I'm not aware of any graphics problems on this computer otherwise.

What is this problem and how might one approach the task of fixing it?

Comment: You should report this to the Ubuntu bug tracker.

Comment: I have been suffering from the same bug for long, and yes, it seems to be related to Intel; I've had similar problems with Eclipse as well, and the solution there was to switch SWT to use GTK2 :/

Comment: Are you running Unity? Which Intel card is it?

Comment: Not related to Intel. I'm having this problem with Gimp on Ubuntu 15.10 with an Nvidia GeForce GTX 960. I am running Unity. The comment about Eclipse caused me to close Eclipse and restart Gimp, at which point Gimp started behaving normally. So... some bad interaction between Gimp + Eclipse + Unity?

Comment: One would assume it is basic functionality of a graphical photo editor to update its UI in real-time... I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Sounds like maybe a Unity/Mir problem.  If you have another Desktop Environment/Window manager installed could you try it with that?

Comment: Does this exist as a ticket anywhere, has a cause (and/or solution) been found? I frequently run into the same issue.